# Map additional values via rest controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have this Rest endpoint which returns table with IDs:

```
    @GetMapping("pages")
    public Page<ContractDTO> pages(@RequestParam(value="page") int page, @RequestParam(value="size") int size) {
      return contractService.findAll(page, size).map(mapper::toDTO);
    }
```

ContractDTO DTO:

```
public class ContractDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Integer gateway;

    private Integer reseller_id;

    private Integer acquirer_id;

    private Integer terminal_id;

    private Integer merchant_id;

    private String descriptor;
    ...
}
```

I store into database table the ID's of each additional component like acquirer_id, terminal_id and etc.

I need to do additional SQL request like `SELECT * FROM acquirers WHERE id = 3`.

How I can make this after I convert the DTO object with Java?

Comment: you can do oneToOneMapping between Id table and acquirers table, and with other details tables

Comment: yes but in my case I would like to skip this and use some other way.